# Trouble with extra characters when printing a variable containing a concatenated string

Tags: python

I've been having an issue with trying to print a variable that contains a concatenated string as seen below:

```
num1 = int(input("Choose a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Choose a second number: "))

total_int = num1 * num2
total_str = total_int, "is the answer"
print(total_str)
```

What I get when I run this (entering 4 and 5 for example) is `(20, 'is the answer')`

Why is it that the parenthesis, single quotations and comma are also printed?
I understand I can get my result without these by doing the following

```
print(num1,'multiplied by',num2,'is',total_int)
```

But I would like to print what is stored in the variable if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually creating a tuple, not concatenating the strings. You can use the `+` operator:

```
num1 = int(input("Choose a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Choose a second number: "))

total_int = num1 * num2
total_str = str(total_int) + " is the answer"
print(total_str)
```

However, format strings are the preferred option:

```
total_str = "{0} is the answer".format(total_int)
```

For Python 3.6+:

```
total_str = f"{total_int} is the answer"
```

If you really wanted to preserve the behavior of passing multiple arguments into `print`, try this:

```
num1 = int(input("Choose a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Choose a second number: "))

total_int = num1 * num2
total_str = total_int, "is the answer"
print(*total_str) # <- notice the `*` operator
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tuple and format have not been discussed in the lessons yet

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input("Choose a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Choose a second number: "))

total_int = num1 * num2
print("{} is the answer".format(total_int))
```

`{}` will print variable Value `.format()` is which value you want to print